# Ruby Gem for comments with mongoid

Tags: rubygems, mongoid

I am in need to integrate comments to my existing mongoid documents. is there any rubygem available to achieve it?

Comment: Do you really need a gem for this? Add a Comment model and create the view to handle the creation.

Comment: Yeah I think a gem for this would be good. Modularity of architecture and such.

Answer (score 2):

usually you'd use   acts_as_commentable

https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable

but it only works with ActiveRecord.

**Use this one for Mongoid:**

https://github.com/mgolovnia/mongoid_commentable

Comment: This library requires ActiveRecord, it's not compatible with Mongoid.